# TCP client server conversation in endless loop?

Tags: http, tcp

I'm trying to access a web server which is sitting behind a Netcomm 3G10WVR modem/router. The web server's port 80 is port forwarded to port 4476 on the router. The tcp conversation seems to proceed ok but then gets into a (seemingly) neverending loop. I exported the conversation from wireshark and deleted the irrelevant lines - the remainder is below:

At frame 138 the client (192.168.1.103) starts a stream of idenical ACKs; the server (12.345.24.155) seems to respond with a stream of identical packet retransmissions

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

```
 
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
     92 18.869627   192.168.1.103         12.345.24.155         TCP      52382 > 4476 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1

     Frame 92: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99), Dst: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103), Dst: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 52382 (52382), Dst Port: 4476 (4476), Seq: 0, Len: 0
         Source port: 52382 (52382)
         Destination port: 4476 (4476)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)
         Header length: 28 bytes
         Flags: 0x02 (SYN)
         Window size: 8192
         Checksum: 0x2593 [validation disabled]
         Options: (8 bytes)

     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         108 18.984785   12.345.24.155         192.168.1.103         TCP      4476 > 52382 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=511 Len=0 MSS=1024

     Frame 108: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0), Dst: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155), Dst: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 4476 (4476), Dst Port: 52382 (52382), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0
         Source port: 4476 (4476)
         Destination port: 52382 (52382)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)
         Acknowledgement number: 1    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 24 bytes
         Flags: 0x12 (SYN, ACK)
         Window size: 511
         Checksum: 0x9a8d [validation disabled]
         Options: (4 bytes)
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [This is an ACK to the segment in frame: 92]
             [The RTT to ACK the segment was: 0.115158000 seconds]

     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         109 18.984874   192.168.1.103         12.345.24.155         TCP      52382 > 4476 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64512 Len=0

     Frame 109: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99), Dst: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103), Dst: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 52382 (52382), Dst Port: 4476 (4476), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0
         Source port: 52382 (52382)
         Destination port: 4476 (4476)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
         Acknowledgement number: 1    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x10 (ACK)
         Window size: 64512
         Checksum: 0x258b [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [This is an ACK to the segment in frame: 108]
             [The RTT to ACK the segment was: 0.000089000 seconds]

     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         110 18.985166   192.168.1.103         12.345.24.155         TCP      52382 > 4476 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64512 Len=468

     Frame 110: 522 bytes on wire (4176 bits), 522 bytes captured (4176 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99), Dst: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103), Dst: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 52382 (52382), Dst Port: 4476 (4476), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 468
         Source port: 52382 (52382)
         Destination port: 4476 (4476)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
         [Next sequence number: 469    (relative sequence number)]
         Acknowledgement number: 1    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x18 (PSH, ACK)
         Window size: 64512
         Checksum: 0x275f [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [Number of bytes in flight: 468]
     Data (468 bytes)

     0000  47 45 54 20 2f 69 6e 64 65 78 2e 68 74 6d 6c 20   GET /index.html 
     0010  48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70 74   HTTP/1.1..Accept
     0020  3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d   : application/x-
     0030  6d 73 2d 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2c 20   ms-application, 
     0040  69 6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70 65 67 2c 20 61 70 70 6c   image/jpeg, appl
     0050  69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 61 6d 6c 2b 78 6d 6c   ication/xaml+xml
     0060  2c 20 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 67 69 66 2c 20 69 6d 61   , image/gif, ima
     0070  67 65 2f 70 6a 70 65 67 2c 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63   ge/pjpeg, applic
     0080  61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d 6d 73 2d 78 62 61 70 2c   ation/x-ms-xbap,
     0090  20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 6d 73 77    application/msw
     00a0  6f 72 64 2c 20 2a 2f 2a 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70 74   ord, */*..Accept
     00b0  2d 4c 61 6e 67 75 61 67 65 3a 20 65 6e 2d 55 53   -Language: en-US
     00c0  0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 4d 6f   ..User-Agent: Mo
     00d0  7a 69 6c 6c 61 2f 34 2e 30 20 28 63 6f 6d 70 61   zilla/4.0 (compa
     00e0  74 69 62 6c 65 3b 20 4d 53 49 45 20 38 2e 30 3b   tible; MSIE 8.0;
     00f0  20 57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20 4e 54 20 36 2e 31 3b    Windows NT 6.1;
     0100  20 57 4f 57 36 34 3b 20 54 72 69 64 65 6e 74 2f    WOW64; Trident/
     0110  34 2e 30 3b 20 47 54 42 36 2e 35 3b 20 53 4c 43   4.0; GTB6.5; SLC
     0120  43 32 3b 20 2e 4e 45 54 20 43 4c 52 20 32 2e 30   C2; .NET CLR 2.0
     0130  2e 35 30 37 32 37 3b 20 2e 4e 45 54 20 43 4c 52   .50727; .NET CLR
     0140  20 33 2e 35 2e 33 30 37 32 39 3b 20 2e 4e 45 54    3.5.30729; .NET
     0150  20 43 4c 52 20 33 2e 30 2e 33 30 37 32 39 3b 20    CLR 3.0.30729; 
     0160  4d 65 64 69 61 20 43 65 6e 74 65 72 20 50 43 20   Media Center PC 
     0170  36 2e 30 3b 20 2e 4e 45 54 34 2e 30 43 29 0d 0a   6.0; .NET4.0C)..
     0180  41 63 63 65 70 74 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a   Accept-Encoding:
     0190  20 67 7a 69 70 2c 20 64 65 66 6c 61 74 65 0d 0a    gzip, deflate..
     01a0  48 6f 73 74 3a 20 37 34 2e 31 39 38 2e 32 34 2e   Host: 12.345.24.
     01b0  31 35 35 3a 34 34 37 36 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63   155:4476..Connec
     01c0  74 69 6f 6e 3a 20 4b 65 65 70 2d 41 6c 69 76 65   tion: Keep-Alive
     01d0  0d 0a 0d 0a                                       ....


     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         134 19.136980   12.345.24.155         192.168.1.103         TCP      4476 > 52382 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=469 Win=511 Len=0

     Frame 134: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0), Dst: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155), Dst: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 4476 (4476), Dst Port: 52382 (52382), Seq: 1, Ack: 469, Len: 0
         Source port: 4476 (4476)
         Destination port: 52382 (52382)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
         Acknowledgement number: 469    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x10 (ACK)
         Window size: 511
         Checksum: 0xaec2 [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [This is an ACK to the segment in frame: 110]
             [The RTT to ACK the segment was: 0.151814000 seconds]


     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         137 19.999665   12.345.24.155         192.168.1.103         TCP      [TCP Previous segment lost] 4476 > 52382 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2801 Ack=469 Win=511 Len=1296

     Frame 137: 1350 bytes on wire (10800 bits), 1350 bytes captured (10800 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0), Dst: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155), Dst: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 4476 (4476), Dst Port: 52382 (52382), Seq: 2801, Ack: 469, Len: 1296
         Source port: 4476 (4476)
         Destination port: 52382 (52382)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 2801    (relative sequence number)
         [Next sequence number: 4097    (relative sequence number)]
         Acknowledgement number: 469    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x18 (PSH, ACK)
         Window size: 511
         Checksum: 0x2932 [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [Number of bytes in flight: 1296]
             [TCP Analysis Flags]
                 [A segment before this frame was lost]
                     [Expert Info (Warn/Sequence): Previous segment lost (common at capture start)]
                         [Message: Previous segment lost (common at capture start)]
                         [Severity level: Warn]
                         [Group: Sequence]
     Data (1296 bytes)

     0000  68 6f 6d 65 2d 78 61 6e 2e 70 6e 67 22 20 61 6c   home-xan.png" al
     0010  74 3d 22 48 6f 6d 65 22 20 2f 3e 3c 2f 61 3e 0d   t="Home" />.
     0020  0a 09 09 09 3c 2f 64 69 76 3e 0d 0a 09 09 09 3c   .................
     0500  0d 0a 09 09 09 09 09 09 3c 74 72 3e 0d 0a 09 09   ............

     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         138 19.999717   192.168.1.103         12.345.24.155         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 110#1] 52382 > 4476 [ACK] Seq=469 Ack=1 Win=64512 Len=0

     Frame 138: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99), Dst: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103), Dst: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 52382 (52382), Dst Port: 4476 (4476), Seq: 469, Ack: 1, Len: 0
         Source port: 52382 (52382)
         Destination port: 4476 (4476)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 469    (relative sequence number)
         Acknowledgement number: 1    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x10 (ACK)
         Window size: 64512
         Checksum: 0x258b [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [TCP Analysis Flags]
                 [This is a TCP duplicate ack]
             [Duplicate ACK #: 1]
             [Duplicate to the ACK in frame: 110]
                 [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Duplicate ACK (#1)]
                     [Message: Duplicate ACK (#1)]
                     [Severity level: Note]
                     [Group: Sequence]

     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         139 20.492179   12.345.24.155         192.168.1.103         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] 4476 > 52382 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2801 Ack=469 Win=511 Len=1296

     Frame 139: 1350 bytes on wire (10800 bits), 1350 bytes captured (10800 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0), Dst: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155), Dst: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 4476 (4476), Dst Port: 52382 (52382), Seq: 2801, Ack: 469, Len: 1296
         Source port: 4476 (4476)
         Destination port: 52382 (52382)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 2801    (relative sequence number)
         [Next sequence number: 4097    (relative sequence number)]
         Acknowledgement number: 469    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x18 (PSH, ACK)
         Window size: 511
         Checksum: 0x2932 [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [Number of bytes in flight: 1296]
             [TCP Analysis Flags]
                 [This frame is a (suspected) retransmission]
                     [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Retransmission (suspected)]
                         [Message: Retransmission (suspected)]
                         [Severity level: Note]
                         [Group: Sequence]
                 [The RTO for this segment was: 0.492514000 seconds]
                 [RTO based on delta from frame: 137]
     Data (1296 bytes)

     0000  68 6f 6d 65 2d 78 61 6e 2e 70 6e 67 22 20 61 6c   home-xan.png" al
     0010  74 3d 22 48 6f 6d 65 22 20 2f 3e 3c 2f 61 3e 0d   t="Home" />.
     0020  0a 09 09 09 3c 2f 64 69 76 3e 0d 0a 09 09 09 3c   .................
     0500  0d 0a 09 09 09 09 09 09 3c 74 72 3e 0d 0a 09 09   ............

     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         140 20.492222   192.168.1.103         12.345.24.155         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 110#2] 52382 > 4476 [ACK] Seq=469 Ack=1 Win=64512 Len=0

     Frame 140: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99), Dst: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103), Dst: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 52382 (52382), Dst Port: 4476 (4476), Seq: 469, Ack: 1, Len: 0
         Source port: 52382 (52382)
         Destination port: 4476 (4476)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 469    (relative sequence number)
         Acknowledgement number: 1    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x10 (ACK)
         Window size: 64512
         Checksum: 0x258b [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [TCP Analysis Flags]
                 [This is a TCP duplicate ack]
             [Duplicate ACK #: 2]
             [Duplicate to the ACK in frame: 110]
                 [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Duplicate ACK (#2)]
                     [Message: Duplicate ACK (#2)]
                     [Severity level: Note]
                     [Group: Sequence]


     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         144 20.974184   12.345.24.155         192.168.1.103         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] 4476 > 52382 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2801 Ack=469 Win=511 Len=1296

     Frame 144: 1350 bytes on wire (10800 bits), 1350 bytes captured (10800 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0), Dst: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155), Dst: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 4476 (4476), Dst Port: 52382 (52382), Seq: 2801, Ack: 469, Len: 1296
         Source port: 4476 (4476)
         Destination port: 52382 (52382)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 2801    (relative sequence number)
         [Next sequence number: 4097    (relative sequence number)]
         Acknowledgement number: 469    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x18 (PSH, ACK)
         Window size: 511
         Checksum: 0x2932 [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [Number of bytes in flight: 1296]
             [TCP Analysis Flags]
                 [This frame is a (suspected) retransmission]
                     [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Retransmission (suspected)]
                         [Message: Retransmission (suspected)]
                         [Severity level: Note]
                         [Group: Sequence]
                 [The RTO for this segment was: 0.974519000 seconds]
                 [RTO based on delta from frame: 137]
     Data (1296 bytes)

     0000  68 6f 6d 65 2d 78 61 6e 2e 70 6e 67 22 20 61 6c   home-xan.png" al
     0010  74 3d 22 48 6f 6d 65 22 20 2f 3e 3c 2f 61 3e 0d   t="Home" />.
     0020  0a 09 09 09 3c 2f 64 69 76 3e 0d 0a 09 09 09 3c   .................
     0500  0d 0a 09 09 09 09 09 09 3c 74 72 3e 0d 0a 09 09   ............

     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         145 20.974229   192.168.1.103         12.345.24.155         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 110#3] 52382 > 4476 [ACK] Seq=469 Ack=1 Win=64512 Len=0

     Frame 145: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99), Dst: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103), Dst: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 52382 (52382), Dst Port: 4476 (4476), Seq: 469, Ack: 1, Len: 0
         Source port: 52382 (52382)
         Destination port: 4476 (4476)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 469    (relative sequence number)
         Acknowledgement number: 1    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x10 (ACK)
         Window size: 64512
         Checksum: 0x258b [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [TCP Analysis Flags]
                 [This is a TCP duplicate ack]
             [Duplicate ACK #: 3]
             [Duplicate to the ACK in frame: 110]
                 [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Duplicate ACK (#3)]
                     [Message: Duplicate ACK (#3)]
                     [Severity level: Note]
                     [Group: Sequence]


     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         147 21.465792   12.345.24.155         192.168.1.103         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] 4476 > 52382 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2801 Ack=469 Win=511 Len=1296

     Frame 147: 1350 bytes on wire (10800 bits), 1350 bytes captured (10800 bits)
     Ethernet II, Src: Cisco-Li_b8:40:a0 (00:13:10:b8:40:a0), Dst: AsustekC_29:44:99 (00:24:8c:29:44:99)
     Internet Protocol, Src: 12.345.24.155 (12.345.24.155), Dst: 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103)
     Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 4476 (4476), Dst Port: 52382 (52382), Seq: 2801, Ack: 469, Len: 1296
         Source port: 4476 (4476)
         Destination port: 52382 (52382)
         [Stream index: 14]
         Sequence number: 2801    (relative sequence number)
         [Next sequence number: 4097    (relative sequence number)]
         Acknowledgement number: 469    (relative ack number)
         Header length: 20 bytes
         Flags: 0x18 (PSH, ACK)
         Window size: 511
         Checksum: 0x2932 [validation disabled]
         [SEQ/ACK analysis]
             [Number of bytes in flight: 1296]
             [TCP Analysis Flags]
                 [This frame is a (suspected) retransmission]
                     [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Retransmission (suspected)]
                         [Message: Retransmission (suspected)]
                         [Severity level: Note]
                         [Group: Sequence]
                 [The RTO for this segment was: 1.466127000 seconds]
                 [RTO based on delta from frame: 137]
     Data (1296 bytes)

     0000  68 6f 6d 65 2d 78 61 6e 2e 70 6e 67 22 20 61 6c   home-xan.png" al
     0010  74 3d 22 48 6f 6d 65 22 20 2f 3e 3c 2f 61 3e 0d   t="Home" />.
     0020  0a 09 09 09 3c 2f 64 69 76 3e 0d 0a 09 09 09 3c   .................
     0500  0d 0a 09 09 09 09 09 09 3c 74 72 3e 0d 0a 09 09   ............

     No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
         148 21.465835   192.168.1.103         12.345.24.155         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 110#4] 52382 > 4476 [ACK] Seq=469 Ack=1 Win=64512 Len=0
```

Answer (score 1):

The client receives a packet with sequence number greater than expected (seq: 2801, acked: 1), so there is a lost packet possibly. The client signals this by sending the ack with the expected byte (1), but the server keeps sending from sequence 2801, thus the endless loop.

Either that first (two-three?) segments always drop out, or there is some buggy TCP implementation alogn the server-routers-client line? I'm interested if you got this sorted.